# Persistent External Panelize in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

I love the External Panelize feature in Midnight Commander, as well as other Panelize features like in Command > Find Files > Panelize. I use it mostly to filter directories then going in and out of them. However, after I change directory, when I go back, the Panelize view is lost and I have to start all over again recreating the Panelize view.

Is there a way to make a certain panelize view persistent over directory navigation?

1. Tried: making a Panelized view, then change to another directory, then go back
2. Expected: the Panelized view is restored
3. Actual result: the Panelized view is retained

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. While you're in the virtual panel (the result of External Panelize) you can view (<kbd>F3</kbd>) and edit (<kbd>F4</kbd>) files. You can even execute shell commands in the command line passing selected/tagged files with `%s`/`%t` and when the command finishes you're back in the virtual panel.

But once you change the current directory you're no longer in the virtual panel, you're in the real directory, and there is no way back.

My advice is to open real directories in the other panel with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>; this way you preserve the virtual panel and opens a real directory at the same time.